# Is there any function for create thumbnail image in php?

Tags: php, image

Is there any function for create thumbnail image in php ?

Comment: Have you already searched Google or here on SO? E.g. http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/create_thumbnail_images.php or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+thumbnail You should find enough information about it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make thumbnails with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525528/how-to-make-thumbnails-with-php)

Comment: i wont ask about how to make thumbnail, just ask about any function for create thumbnail...

Comment: i hope this question is raised already...please check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Remove a table column in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545528/how-do-i-remove-a-table-column-in-mvc)

Comment: @ john, please understand my question.  How are you relate my question with that question. I didn't get any answer of my question so only i asked.

Answer (score 3):

There's no single function that will create the thumbnail for you, but there are several functions that are part of the GD library, like [`imagecreatetruecolor`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) and [`imagecopyresampled`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php).  The best thing you could do is start with a tutorial, Google knows best here:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gd+php+thumbnail

Answer (score 1):

you have a GD library function for image creation...pls follow the URL

```
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to generate the image thumbnail without changing the aspect ratio of the original image. And here $img is the path of image where original image is stored.

```
            $sourceAppImgPath = $this->images->absPath($img);
            $file_dimensions = getimagesize($sourceAppImgPath);
            $ImageType = strtolower($file_dimensions['mime']);

                switch(strtolower($ImageType))
                {
                    case 'image/png':
                        $image = imagecreatefrompng($sourceAppImgPath);
                        break;
                    case 'image/gif':
                        $image = imagecreatefromgif($sourceAppImgPath);
                        break;
                    case 'image/jpeg':
                        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceAppImgPath);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return false; //output error
                }

                    $origWidth = imagesx($image);
                    $origHeight = imagesy($image);
                    $maxWidth = 300;
                    $maxHeight =300;

                    if ($maxWidth == 0)
                        $maxWidth  = $origWidth;

                    if ($maxHeight == 0)
                        $maxHeight = $origHeight;

                    $widthRatio = $maxWidth / $origWidth;
                    $heightRatio = $maxHeight / $origHeight;
                    $ratio = min($widthRatio, $heightRatio);
                    $thumb_width  = (int)$origWidth  * $ratio;
                    $thumb_height = (int)$origHeight * $ratio;
```